# Git integration

Tags: git, shell

So I was trying to experiment with console applications and managed to connect to TFS, then checkout or checkin files. I wanted to be able to collect information about the files, and then store them in a notepad (in the future I will store in database).

Anyway, I wanted to now work using shell scripts and instead of TFS, wanted to use Git (Gitorious for now) to pull and push contents. However, this seems to be real difficult. The public/private keys are a problem and I'm unsure how to work it out. Someone suggested me to access content by ssh, but I have never tried that out. Can someone point me the way to get started and what I should look at or do?

Comment: be more precise in what is your particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH is a good way to do it, but you need to generate your public and private keys.
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys will explain how to generate keys.
After that's done, you need to clone the repository from an SSH url. It will look sort of like this: git@github.com:username/repo.git. You can then run

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

and git will clone the repository to a directory of the same name.
If you get stuck, the Github help is helpful and is not specific to Github in most cases.

Comment: yes, i managed to get one using PutTy generator. But, this looks like a good guide, and could be useful for my code. I shall keep the GitHub help in mind. Thanks!